# Limit category to a specific customer segment

Tags: magento-1, category-products, customer-segmentation

In my store (mage-EE v12) I have a category that i want to restrict to a specific customer segment. Does anyone know of a way i can do this? 
EG, if i set up a segment, I want customers in this segment to have access to the full catalog, but if the customers does not fall into this segment they have no visibility of the restricted category?  
Any thoughts ? 
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement.

- *First you need to create a new customer group from admin .*
- *Assign  specific customer segment to this Group.*
- Then using event/observer `catalog_controller_category_init_before`
  prevent customer to go this category except  that specific 
  category

**config.xml :**

```
<config>
  <global>
    <config>
      <events>
        <catalog_controller_category_init_after>
          <observers>
            <redirect_to_account>
              <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer/class>
              <method>redirectNotLogged</method>
            </redirect_to_account>
          </observers>
        </catalog_controller_category_init_after>
      </events>
    </config>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php 
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{

    public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName());
        $controller = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
        $controller_action= $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
        /* if category is not Match with your category then continue default behave */
        if($category->getId()!='YOUR_CATEGORY_ID'):
            return true;
        endif;

        /* Customer group id match and then previllage to access that category page.*/
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()=='CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID') {
           return  true;
        }

        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Or use  extension like**

- [Vinai Kopp](https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2)
- [Amasty](https://amasty.com/customer-group-catalog.html)
- [Atwix](https://www.atwix.com/magento/restricting-actions-by-a-customer-group-in-magento/)

Comment: how to do the same in magento 2